# ANDROID: Did not find Xamarin.Android

Tags: windows, xamarin, xamarin.android

Following the guide here:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/
I wanted to install Xamarin Studio Manually (not Visual studio), because I already build native Android apps with the Android SDK/NDK. This guide has the following comment: "When using Windows you have a choice of IDE – Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio".

The Xamarin Studio IDE starts but I have this problem (cannot select "Android" as a mobile target):
[Target Platform is disabled in Xamarin Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35625345/target-platform-is-disabled-in-xamarin-studio)

The Ide.*.log file says:

> INFO [2016-06-29 13:33:32Z]: ANDROID: sdk:   Key
>   HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidSdkDirectory found:
>       Path contains adb.exe in \platform-tools (C:\bin\android_sdk). INFO [2016-06-29 13:33:32Z]: ANDROID: sdk:   Key
>   HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidNdkDirectory found:
>       Path contains ndk-stack.exe in . (C:\bin\android_ndk). INFO [2016-06-29 13:33:32Z]: ANDROID: sdk:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono
>   for Android\JavaSdkDirectory found:
>       Path contains jarsigner.exe in \bin (C:\bin\java\jdk). INFO [2016-06-29 13:33:32Z]: ANDROID: Did not find Xamarin.Android INFO
>   [2016-06-29 13:33:32Z]: ANDROID: Found Android SDK. API levels: (none)
>
> ERROR [2016-06-29 13:33:32Z]: Error detecting Xamarin.Android SDK
>   System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

- I have added a name in the configure project dialog
- Going to Add-ons Xamarin.Android is enabled.

Any ideas how to solve the issue?

Comment: I'm facing the [same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39486189/3967440), please let me know if you could get ride of it.

Comment: no, i wasn't able to solve the issue for Xamarin Studio on Windows, so i've moved to using Xamarin for Visual Studio 2015 and that works OK. the Xamarin platform has it's strong sides, but i would not recommend it over writing OS specific version of an App - e.g. one for native Android and one for native iOS.