# Visual Studio 2015 unable to find Android API Level

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

When I'm trying to create `Xamarin Forms` project, VS gives me the following error for `Android project`:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The output is:

> [I:sdk]: Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidSdkDirectory found: Path contains adb.exe in \platform-tools (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk).
>
> [I:sdk]: Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidNdkDirectory found: Path contains ndk-stack.exe in . (C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r10e).
>
> [I:sdk]: Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\JavaSdkDirectory found: Path contains jarsigner.exe in \bin (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51).
>
> [I:Unknown]: Found Android SDK. API levels: (none)

I think the issue is because of the last line, `API levels: (none)`. This picture shows SDK Manager, and that I have installed `API 23`.

[image: SDK Manager]

Any troubleshooting tip is welcome!

**UPDATE**

If I try to build existing projects, I'll get the following exceptions:

> "No Android platforms installed at '{0}'. Please install an SDK Platform with the `{1}{2}tools{2}{3}` program."
>
> Could not determine $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for API level '-2147483648.' App1

And this is the output:

> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(569,2): error XA5300: "No Android platforms installed at '{0}'. Please install an SDK Platform with the `{1}{2}tools{2}{3}` program."
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(569,2): error XA5300: System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(569,2): error XA5300:    at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(569,2): error XA5300:    at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(569,2): error XA5300:    at System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(569,2): error XA5300:    at Microsoft.Build.Framework.LazyFormattedBuildEventArgs.FormatString(CultureInfo culture, String unformatted, Object[] args)
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(569,2): error XA0000: Could not determine $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for API level '-2147483648.'

Does anyone know what are `{0..3}` placeholders?

Comment: dumb question, but did you tried re-installing your Android SDK?

Comment: Yes, I've reinstalled just anything!

Comment: I just googled a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33151156/6635287 try #3

Comment: Thank you Radinator, but I have tried that too! I've spent hours googling! :-|

Comment: can you give us a complete screenshot over all installed and not installed packages in your SDK manager?

Comment: That pic shows all I have installed; anything not there, is not installed! ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123356/discussion-between-radinator-and-akbari).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only installing latest [Xamarin](http://download.xamarin.com/XamarinforVisualStudio/Windows/Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.2.0.695.msi) solved the problem.

I've tried installing `SDK` and `NDK` with `Visual Studio` installer, or upgrading `Platform API`, and reinstalling everything, and none of them worked. Including [this answer](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/204225/#Comment_204225).